# A type error: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment. How can I fix that?

Tags: typeerror

I'm running the following code and got a type error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment
```

Here's my code:

```
N_object4 = 4
alpha = np.random.normal(0, 10, N_object4)# Random alpha values (could be greater or less than 0.)
pa = np.abs(alpha)
num = pa.argsort()[-3:][::-1]
gs = np.zeros(N_object4).tolist
for i in range (len(num)): # Iterating from largest abs(alpha) to the smallest.
    if alpha[num[i]] > 0:
        gs[num[i]+1] = 1
```

The error happens in my last line. How can I fix this error? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its small typo in line 4. You should use `tolist()`:

```py
gs = np.zeros(N_object4).tolist()
```